# how to manipulate font properties of text above overbracket

Tags: math-mode, fontsize, text-manipulation

How can I change the font properties (e.g. size, style, spacing etc) of text above a overbracket in an equation?

For example:

```
\overbrace{10000r^{n}-750\left(\frac{1-r^{n}}{1-r}\right)}^\text{expression for any year}
```

I want to change the font size of the sentence `expression for any year` to become larger.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular font size/attribute changing commands work inside the `\text{....}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\overbrace{10000r^{n}-750\left(\frac{1-r^{n}}{1-r}\right)}^\text{\large expression for any year}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot but I would like to konw where can I get the list of font attribute command? I would like to have more manipulation like the actual font size, spacing etc to it. I am still very new to latex. this is just my second day of using it.

Comment: @user25196: you can use `\fontsize{<size>}{<interline skip>}\selectfont` as in `\text{\sffamily\fontsize{14}{17}\selectfont expression for any year}`. Here sizes will be in `pt`. `\sffamily` (or `\textsf{...}`) will produce `sans` font. Similarly you have `\bfseries` (or `\textbf{...}`), `\ttfamily`, `\itshape` etc. Sorry for not providing a link. No time now for searching. Please search in this site.